# SendKeys Ctrl-A not working

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I'm trying to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>  (select all to an app in this case word but try as I might it doesn't work) I've tried quite a few combinations but all to no avail, any ideas?

```
        IntPtr appHandle = FindWindow(null, "Document1 - Microsoft Word");
        if (appHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Specified app is not running.");
            return;
        }

        SetForegroundWindow(appHandle);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        //SendKeys.SendWait("111");
        SendKeys.SendWait("^A");
        //SendKeys.SendWait("^(A)"); //ctrl a
        //SendKeys.SendWait("(^A)");
```

Answer (score 45):

To specify that any combination of <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, and <kbd>ALT</kbd> should be held down while several other keys are pressed, enclose the code for those keys in parentheses. For example, to specify to hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> are pressed, use `+(EC)`. To specify to hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while <kbd>E</kbd> is pressed, followed by <kbd>C</kbd> without <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, use `+EC`.

Answer is:

```
SendKeys.Send("^(a)");
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer... unfortunate that OP didn't select one.

Comment: That's not the answer, it clearly states that if only one key is needed by the control key, there is no need for the parentheses.

Answer (score 16):

I got same problem 
I want select text an input text control

SendKeys.SendWait("^A") doesn't works nor Sendkeys.SendWait "^A" doessn't works

Sendkeys.SendWait("^a") works ok

for more info:
   http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm

hth

Answer (score 6):

SendKeys is case-sensitive. Try this:

```
SendKeys.Send("^a");
```

I'm not sure, but it seems like

```
SendKeys.Send("^A");
```

means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. At least it does work this way in some applications.

Comment: The Shift code is +, so if you want capital A you would have to do ("+^a")

Answer (score 4):

Did you try

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^{A}");
```

Comment: tried this and this doesn't work.
Tried use alt key combos and they don't work for me either....

Answer (score 2):

been through this.

The only working solution:

Find your element where you want to enter text

```
     element.SetFocus();

     Thread.Sleep(2000);

     SendKeys.SendWait("^{HOME}");  // Move to start of control

     SendKeys.SendWait("^+{END}"); // Select everything

     SendKeys.SendWait("{DEL}"); 

     SendKeys.SendWait("Value");
```